# What is syntactically wrong with this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the code that's preventing a page from displaying, and I think this legacy function may be the culprit:

```
function SetTabOrder() {
    $.each([
            "#BeginDate",
            "#BeginTime",
            "#EndDate",
            "#EndTime",
            "#InputSite-input",
            "#cmdAddSite",
            "#InputDept-input",
            "#cmdAddDept",
            "#IncludeDepts",
            "#ExcludeDepts",
            "#UPCBeginsWith"], 
        function(i, n) {
            $(n).prop("taborder", "y");
        }
}
```

The "each" bit looks wrong, or at least weird, to me, and I appended a right paren to the right angle bracket, like so:

```
"#UPCBeginsWith"]),
```

...but jsFiddle/JSHint tells me, "Missing name in function declaration"

If I remove that paren, it gives me two errors, one on the first line:

```
Unmatched '{'
```

...and one on the last line:

```
"Missing semicolon."
```

However, adding a semicolon to the end changes nothing.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a closing parenthesis for $.each(. It should be placed after the "function(i, n)...", so that it ends like "});".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's original cause is a syntax error.

Comment: you shouldn't try to "fix" code by randomly adding parentheses/semicolons... that's just *wrong*. first try to understand what it does. for example, have you looked up what `$.each` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function SetTabOrder() {
    $.each(["#BeginDate",
            "#BeginTime",
            "#EndDate",
            "#EndTime",
            "#InputSite-input",
            "#cmdAddSite",
            "#InputDept-input",
            "#cmdAddDept",
            "#IncludeDepts",
            "#ExcludeDepts",
            "#UPCBeginsWith"], 
        function(i, n) {
            $(n).prop("taborder", "y");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the location of the missing parenthesis is after the callback function:

```
  $.each( an_array, function(){
    // callback
  });
//-^---- this one
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.each` is a function call, and as such needs to have a closing parenthesis (and should also have a semicolon).

```
$.each([
    ...
], function () {
    ...
});← here's your issue
```

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to close the call to each.

```
function SetTabOrder() {
    $.each([
        "#BeginDate",
        "#BeginTime",
        "#EndDate",
        "#EndTime",
        "#InputSite-input",
        "#cmdAddSite",
        "#InputDept-input",
        "#cmdAddDept",
        "#IncludeDepts",
        "#ExcludeDepts",
        "#UPCBeginsWith"], 
    function(i, n) {
        $(n).prop("taborder", "y");
    })
}
```

It will help you, if you use an editor, which can match the parenthesis. With VI for example you can hit the % sign to jump to matching character. For windows is [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) a good choice, for unix [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vi](http://www.vim.org/).

Comment: With a semicolon on the penultimate line, that satisfies jsfiddle.

Comment: @ClayShannon I thought it was not required by the standard, but it is sloppy code.